# How do I remove n characters from the beginning of a txt file in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, f#, stream

I know you can do it by just overwriting the whole file contents via File.WriteAllText or similar function. But it doesn't seem like it's an effective way of removing a couple of characters at start, especially if text file contains more than millions of characters.

Is there a way I can do it using some FileStream / other Stream classes functions?

Comment: How do you think it should be done? Altering the File Allocation table and chop some of the blocks?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if it's possible at all, but who knows..

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I thought maybe OS could do it for me in an efficient way

Comment: If you're on linux, FFI into `fallocate` and an option like `FALLOC_FL_COLLAPSE_RANGE` to 'remove' byte ranges from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the need, you can do Seek() and then CopyTo() to a new stream.

```
using (FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(FileName1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{ 
    fs1.Seek(N, SeekOrigin.Begin); // N - number of characters from the beginning
    using (FileStream fs2 = File.Create(FileName2))
        fileStream1.CopyTo(fs2);
}
```

To remove first lines, do

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(FileName1);
File.WriteAllLines(FileName2, lines.Skip(N).ToArray());
```

Comment: The point is to not overwrite the whole file, but to just somehow remove first n characters within N complexity. I was wondering if it was possible to do - maybe somehow with OS assistance